# Can't use static library in a titanium module

Tags: objective-c, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am trying to add a static library to a titanium iphone module i have created, and it seems that whenever i add the library to the "Link binary with libraries", and use `titanium run` titanium returns the following error:

```
[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
[DEBUG] File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.2/iphone/builder.py", line 1148, in main
[DEBUG] execute_xcode("iphonesimulator%s" % link_version,["GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=__LOG__ID__=%s DEPLOYTYPE=development TI_DEVELOPMENT=1 DEBUG=1 TI_VERSION=%s %s" % (log_id,sdk_version,debugstr)],False)
[DEBUG] File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.2/iphone/builder.py", line 1066, in execute_xcode
[DEBUG] output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
[DEBUG] File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.2/iphone/run.py", line 39, in run
[DEBUG] sys.exit(rc)
[DEBUG] SystemExit: 65
[ERROR] Build Failed. See: /var/folders/ot/ot5FPlA3EZyk6n8ZnYeWxk+++TI/-Tmp-/m9mX89ati/test2/build/iphone/build/build.log
```

build.log shows:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test2.app/test2 normal i386
(1 failure)
EXIT CODE WAS: 65

Exception detected in script:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.2/iphone/builder.py", line 1148, in main
    execute_xcode("iphonesimulator%s" % link_version,["GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=__LOG__ID__=%s DEPLOYTYPE=development TI_DEVELOPMENT=1 DEBUG=1 TI_VERSION=%s %s" % (log_id,sdk_version,debugstr)],False)
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.2/iphone/builder.py", line 1066, in execute_xcode
    output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.2/iphone/run.py", line 39, in run
    sys.exit(rc)
SystemExit: 65
```

I'm desperate, anyone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this section of the documentation

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Module+Developer+Guide+for+iOS#ModuleDeveloperGuideforiOS-AddingSpecialCompilerDirectives

Comment: Thanks for the response, i added this line: `OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -lib {library name}` to the module.xcconfig file, and it throws the same error. should it be {library name}.a or just the name without the extension? is it possible that titanium doesn't support this library?

Answer (score 0):

add this line to the module.xcconfig

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -framework GameKit
```

where GameKit is your missing framework that is used in your library.